# Creating a widget

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

Hi i want to create a widget which can be embedded on other websites similar to the twitter profile widget, an example is here;

http://twitter.com/about/resources/widgets/widget_profile

The way i would approach this is to return the data in json format via my wcf, the problem is looking at the twitter example there seems to be some javascript and i am not to clued up on the purpose. My question to the more experienced devlopers is am i on the right track and what else will i need to do. Thanks alot

Comment: unfortunately your link is broken and the question is not clear enough anymore :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of the javascript would be to actually call your wcf service to retrieve data and write the html results to the screen. In the twitter example, many options are set inside a javascript object that is used to manage the configuration (background color, username, etc). You can return json, and then take the values from json and plug them into an html template on the client side. If you want this to be used on other sites however, I would probably avoid the use of jquery as you can't be sure the user has included it, and so you would need to include it. And then you have versioning issues if you use an older version, and the website your widget is on wants to use a newer version.

Comment: Thanks for replying,  whats the alternative to using jquery if i may ask?

Comment: @pmillio - The alternative is to do your own DOM manipulation. It's not fun, and you will have to deal with cross browser issues yourself, but you won't have any dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

There is an interesting blog post that explains how to create a widget, loading jquery and css safely, making [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) calls and more:
[How to build a web widget (using jQuery)](http://alexmarandon.com/articles/web_widget_jquery/)

Comment: Interesting stuff: Webcomponents + JSONP